# Would like to put this data in two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to append the first value into one list and the other into another list. I assume it's very simple just having a mind blank.

i.e. 0,47, 15,790, 45,1200, 99,14890

One list has 0 57 45 99
and the second has 47 790 1200 and 14890

Also please note that in the file [0] would be equal to zero and [1] = , [3] = 4

```html
    num = 0 
    old_num = num
    
    while num < len(custom)
        num +=1
        if custom[old_num:num] in nums and custom[num-1] == ',':
            load_percentage.append(custom[old_num:num])
            num+=1
        elif custom[old_num:num] in nums:
            hours.append(custom[old_num:num])
            num+=1
        elif custom[num:num+1] == ', ': 
            num +=2
            old_num = num
        elif custom[num] == ',':
            num +=1
            old_num = num
        else: 
            hours.append(custom[old_num:num])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What I have tried is doing a for loop with if, elif statements etc. that for example if the next two data sets is, it appends to a different list then if they say it is just comma append to another list: just can't seem to get it to work, unfortunately.

Comment: You should include the code for your attempt in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you working on a string?

```
def main():
    custom = '0,47, 15,790, 45,1200, 99,14890'
    # Get rid of spaces and split the string to values in a list.
    values = custom.replace(' ', '').split(',')
    load_percentage = []
    hours = []
    for i, val in enumerate(values):
        # Every index that is divisible by 2 will go to 
        # load percentage (0, 2..)
        if i % 2 == 0:
            load_percentage.append(val)
        else:
            hours.append(val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use appropriate `split` and slicing:

```py
data = '0,47, 15,790, 45,1200, 99,14890'

lst = [int(x) for x in data.split(',')] # int deals with the whitespaces
output1 = lst[::2]
output2 = lst[1::2]

print(output1) # [0, 15, 45, 99]
print(output2) # [47, 790, 1200, 14890]
```

Of course converting to `int` is not mandatory; you can first replace the whitespaces into an empty string and then split by `,` as the other answer suggests.